# Lateral area of a cone with oblique base (elliptical base)

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

Can someone help me find the lateral area of a straight circular cone with oblique base ( inclined elliptical base) as seen at the following link.

http://chestofbooks.com/crafts/metal/Sheet-And-Plate-Metal-Work/Elliptical-Cone-Or-Cap.html#.U1bRC9w3cpE

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Interesting: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.5946.pdf